# Не устанавливается разрешение окна

Tags: python, html, eel

Работаю с библиотекой `eel`. Я устанавливаю разрешение 500х500, а приложение открывается у меня в таком разрешении (фото)

сам код (python):

```
import eel

eel.init("web")

eel.start("main.html",size=(500,500))
```

код html:
тут можно просто шаблон с hello world

[image: само фото]

Comment: разрешение*
Был бы рад помощи )

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите Ваш код прямо в вопрос (текстом), чтобы мы смогли скопировать и запустить его. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 0):

В коде html нужно было написать:

```
<script src="eel.js"></script>
```

У меня было:

```
<script type="eel.js"></script>
```